# What brazilian snake is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology, snake

(1) Is it possible to identify the snake in the picture below?

If (1) cannot be answered:

(2) In view of the pattern of colors, is it possible the snake in the picture below be non-venomous? If so, what kind of non-venomous snake?

*Additional informations:*

- Size: 62cm.
- Region: South of Brazil, noutrh of [Paraná](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paran%C3%A1_(state)).
- I do not have a picture of the head.

*Pictures:*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangular pattern and the lightly colored underside resemble typical patterns of Bothrops (lancehead viper). Without the head it is quite difficult to tell which species this is. Given the location, the most common lancehead viper would be Bothrops jajaraca, simply called Jararaca by the locals.

[Images can be found here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bothrops_jararaca)